# Create new folders within multiple existing folders with python

Tags: python, directory

I am looking for a way to create new folders within multiple existing folders. For example I have folders a,b,c.. etc and I want to create a new folder inside each of these existing folders and name the new folders a1,b1,c1,.. etc. using a python script.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I've tried this <<< import os root_path = '/my/root/path/' folders = ['a1','b1','c1'] for folder in folders: os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,folder))

Comment: I forgot to say that what i did above did nothing at all. Sorry about the formating. Am still trying to figure it out. I can't find any tips in the faqs for the life of me...:(

Answer (score 1):

Try looping through your list of folders rather than passing in the list.  It is not the cleanest method out there but you can do something like:

```
parents = [p1, p2, p3]
childern = [c1, c2, c3]

for p in parents:
   for c in children:
      os.mkdir(os.path.join(p,c))
```

Comment: That I did.  I am going to go ahead and blame someone else for my mistake.