# Creating similar multiple sub-folders in multiple different folders using python

Tags: python, directory

How do I create a multiple different folders that also contain multiple different folders using python?
My path is: './work/animals/'. The 'animals' directory contains the folders 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'mouse', 'lion', 'cheetah', 'rat', 'baboon', 'donkey', 'snake' and 'giraffe'.
I have managed to write the part that creates all the animal folders (code below), but I also wanted to create three other subfolders namely 'male', 'female' and 'uncategorized' in all the folders in animals.

```
import os
root_path = './work/animals/'
folders = ['cat','dog','horse','mouse','lion','cheetah','rat','baboon','donkey','snake','giraffe']

for folder in folders:
     os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,folder))
```

Comment: Can you write out the paths of these directories you want to create?  That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506864/create-new-folders-within-multiple-existing-folders-with-python?rq=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply doing :

```
import os
root_path = './work/animals/'
folders = ['cat','dog','horse','mouse','lion','cheetah','rat','baboon','donkey','snake','giraffe']
subfolders = ['male', 'female', 'uncategorized']
for folder in folders:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,folder))
    for subfolder in subfolders : 
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(root_path,folder,subfolder))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product` to get the combinations of animals plus gender that you want and then use `os.makedirs` which will create intermediate directories for you.

```
import os
import itertools

root_path = './work/animals/'

folders = ['cat','dog','horse','mouse','lion','cheetah','rat','baboon','donkey','snake','giraffe']
genders = ['male', 'female', 'uncategorized']

for folder,gender in itertools.product(folders, genders):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(root_path,folder,gender))
```